# persistent label encoding in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, pipeline

Ho can I persistently encode the same String to the same column?
[Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn) propose a nice way to handle a data frame with multiple categorical values. However, I am unsure if this correctly persists (in a pickle) and would apply the same labels again for freshly incoming data.

So far I used pandas directly and obtained the labels via `.cat.codes` of the category values. But Now I need to integrate label encoding into a pipeline to deal with fresh incoming data.

Would something like

```
le = LabelEncoder()
for col in df.select_dtypes([], ['object'].columns:
    df[col] = le.fit_transform(df[col])
```

Or the proposed solution of the `MultiColumnLabelEncoder` suffice for my task?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be already handled for the single column case [Usng same Label Encoder to test dataset? or new Label Encoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133192/usng-same-label-encoder-to-test-dataset-or-new-label-encoder)

So I used the aforementioned multi-column solution should which worked fine.

Comment: this answer meas that you need to have the entire dataframe in memory at inference time. Far from ideal.

Comment: @marbel I understand. What solution would you propose?

Comment: Just to leave it here as a reference, I've answered the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321232/handling-unknown-values-for-label-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same problem and was able to find a work around, if we can save the encoder instance info, we may reuse it to produce expected outputs. 
below link has the detailed answer to it:
[Using Scikit's LabelEncoder correctly across multiple programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656736/using-scikits-labelencoder-correctly-across-multiple-programs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656736/using-scikits-labelencoder-correctly-across-multiple-programs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

For more generic approach, [here](https://gist.github.com/Zilch123/91aa36c364b90f9f23bb141cb0095da2) is a custom function for fit and transform separately,

- The fit function gets train DataFrame and categorical columns list returns a Dict of label encoder classes.
- The Dict is pickled and loaded at the inference.
- The transform function gets Inference DataFrame, categorical columns list and the encoder Dict pickle path and returns the label encoded DataFrame.

For function code and working example, please refer here,

Source: [Link](https://gist.github.com/Zilch123/91aa36c364b90f9f23bb141cb0095da2)