# How to convert string labels to numeric values

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a csv file(delimiter=,) containing following fields

```
filename labels
xyz.png  cat
pqz.png  dog
abc.png  mouse
```

there is a list containing all the classes

```
data-classes = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"]
```

Question : How to replace the string labels in csv with the index of the labels data-classes (i.e. if `label == cat` then label should change to 0 ) and save it in csv file.

Comment: is this what your looking for? I would anyway advice to use pandas to reada and write the csv http://fastml.com/converting-categorical-data-into-numbers-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/

Comment: Related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133192/usng-same-label-encoder-to-test-dataset-or-new-label-encoder

Comment: LabelEncoder doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that all classes are present in your list you can do this using `apply` and call `index` on the list to return the ordinal position of the class in the list:

```
In[5]:
df['labels'].apply(data_classes.index)

Out[5]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```

However, it will be faster to define a dict of your mapping and pass this an use `map` IMO as this is cython-ised so should be faster:

```
In[7]:
d = dict(zip(data_classes, range(0,3)))
d

Out[7]: {'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'mouse': 2}

In[8]:
df['labels'].map(d, na_action='ignore')

Out[8]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```

If there are classes not present then `NaN` is returned

Comment: for `.apply(data_classes.index)` I get `TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable`

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari this still works for me, so I can't comment unless you post a new question with a full reproducible example

Comment: @EdChum data_classes is the same with data-classes from the question?

Comment: I am trying to adopt your code into my, but it says 'Int64Index' object is not callable', is there any way to overcome this?