# TypeError: Cannot convert value dtype to a TensorFlow DType

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am fairly new to tensorflow. I am loading a model from a .h5 file and trying to make a prediction using the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_path = '/path/to/file'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_path)

query = np.array(('cat1', 69.0, 'cat2', 9.2, 'cat3', 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 43, 1200, 4380), dtype='U32, float32, U32, float32, U32, uint16, uint16, uint16, uint16, uint16, uint16, uint16, float32, float32')
result = model.predict(query)
```

I tried to format the query as pandas.Series but couldn't get it working with mixed data types. I explicitly specified the dtype using np.array but it was throwing the error: "TypeError: Cannot convert value dtype to a TensorFlow DType."

cat1, cat2 and cat3 are categories and have been labelencoded during model training.

During testing, I found that the model is returning a prediction if I pass uint16 values instead of U32 in the query np.array. But I can't figure out how to get the uint16 values for the categories. Or how to format the array to create the tensor for prediction. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `query` array is a single element (0d) with a compound dtype (14 fields with mixed dtypes).  That may be good for loading data from a `csv` file, but we know nothing about what the `keras` model expects.  The error says it can't convert that compound dtype to a TersorFlow object.

Comment: The `keras` model returns predictions when cat1, cat2 and cat3 are passed as uint16 with all other dtypes being the same as in np.array.

Comment: 'U32' is a string dtype. 'uint16' is a number.  The model may be expecting a finite number of categories encoded as numbers rather than as words.

Comment: Could be but then how do I convert the strings into the encoded numbers? If there wa some way of getting this info from the model, does it mean that I have to get this information from the model every time the it is rebuilt?

Comment: I resolved the issue by encoding the categories as per this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656736/using-scikits-labelencoder-correctly-across-multiple-programs